# How do I display my list control in Report View. I want to see the VIEW on the properties of list control visual studio 2013 update 4

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, listbox, listctrl

Please, I am having problem with my control list in MFC programs, I use visual studio 2013. On the properties of the control list, I cannot access VIEW. The list control cannot display columns.

Some errors  I get are:

```
"CListBox" has no member "InsertColumn";
"CListBox" has no member "SetItemText";
```

How can I make my control list to be in Report View?

```
    // Column width and heading
m_ListControl.InsertColumn(0, "Emp ID", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 0);
m_ListControl.InsertColumn(1, "Name", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);
m_ListControl.InsertColumn(2, "Age", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);
m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(0, 120);
m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(1, 200);
m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(2, 200);

// Insert values into the list control
iRec = m_ListControl.InsertItem(0, strID, 0);
m_ListControl.SetItemText(0, 1, strName);
m_ListControl.SetItemText(0, 2, strAge);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is CListBox.  Can you please, help me with errors. Also, on the properties of list box, I can't locate view.

Comment: Don't use CListBox, use CListCtrl. There is no View property for CListBox, only for CListCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

[`CListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-160) and [`CListCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistbox-class?view=msvc-160) are two different control types.

`CListCtrl` is what you are clearly wanting, yet the error messages you get indicate you have added a `CListBox`.